# install all grunt devDependencies using one command

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I just setup my Gruntfile.js file and loads all(9) devDependencies. To install these devDependencies, I used following command

```
npm install name-of-plugin --save-dev
```

I used above command 9 times for each dependency. Now what I want is to install all these dependency using one command something like `grunt install plugins` or something else command. That command will read devDependencies from package.json file and install it for me.

**Is this possible? If yes then how can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add `deveDependencies` in `package.json` and `npm install`

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "projectname",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {},

  "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jade": "*",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~0.1.11",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.3.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.1.0"
  }
}
```

then run

```
 npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know your dependencies name then you try like this -

```
npm install grunt-contrib-sass grunt-contrib-uglify --save
```